# How Do I Stop My Web Content From Shifting Left When The Vertical Scrollbar Appears? Roll-Up of Advice 2017

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Many programmers have asked how to stop their web page content — especially their centered web page content (`margin: 0 auto;`) — from shifting (being pushed) horizontally when the vertical scroll bar appears. This has been an ongoing problem for Ajax users and people like me who use hidden divs and tabs to organize data.

The problem occurs when the currently displayed page changes such that the height of the displayed material (the inner window height) is suddenly greater than the physical window height.

The problem is exacerbated by the reality that all scrollbars are not created equal. Different browsers give their scroll bars different widths, and that difference cannot (or, at least, should not) be predicted. In short, the ideal solution is scrollbar width independent.

This, therefore, is a self-answered question that rolls all those answers with commentary on their usefullness (where possible) along with my own solution into a single answer as of August 5, 2017. I've marked as duplicates as many of the previous questions as I can find so that people can find a comprehensive discussion of the issue.

*Please note that this answer addresses problems with BODY contents shifting. If you have a DIV with a fixed height that has shifting problems, you should set the DIV width to a fixed (`px`) width so its scrollbar floats above the text and add some right-hand padding to keep the text from falling beneath it.  Contributors: [Hashbrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome/18548709#18548709),
[Avrahamcool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208826/preventing-relayout-due-to-scrollbar/19209997#19209997),
[Edward Newsome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/29579274#29579274)*

Comment: @mercator, I have already flagged that post and another 9 or 10 as duplicates of this post --- and I doubt I found all the many duplicates of this question that are out there.  Further, that post does not answer my original question and does not have a comprehensive answer.

Comment: This one has lesser votes but it is older: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341465/prevent-a-centered-layout-from-shifting-its-position-when-scrollbar-appears

Comment: @Salaman A... I've already flagged that one, too.  There are a **lot** of these out there that since 2009 have not been flagged duplicates of one another.  Honestly, I'm just trying to do everyone a favor by rolling all the good data up into a single place --- especially since none of them answered the question in a way that worked for me.

Comment: Moderators.  Elements of this question are not answered by either of the questions indicated or, indeed, by any of the 11 known "duplicate" questions (I believe none of which are marked "duplicate" at all) this Q/A is meant to supercede.  However, I'm delighted to accept your ruling as the page will remain intact to help others, which is its intent.  Thank you.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Before going into individual solutions, it should be mentioned that they break down into three categories: CSS-, CSS3-, and Javascript-based solutions.

The CSS solutions tend to be rigid but very predictable and very well supported.

The CSS3 solutions have a CPU calculation cost like Javascript, but are easy to implement. In years previous to 2017, however, they had sporadic support in browsers. That is improving over time. Ultimately, they will likely be the best solution, but my own investigations today have demonstrated the support simply isn't consistent enough yet and, besides, legacy browser support is non-existent.

The Javascript solutions (whether in straight Javascript or in jQuery) need extra coding to make them robust as they have no intrinsic support for (e.g.) window resizing. However, they're the most predictable and the most backward compatible while still preserving the aesthetics of the page. I consider the line for legacy browsers to be between IE6 and IE7. Frankly, my condolences to anyone still using a browser that old.

Please note that I ***have not*** included every CSS3 and Javascript solution previously posted to Stack Exchange. Some, though novel, had substantial weaknesses and so were not included here.

---

**Solution #1: The CSS Solution**

*Contributors: [Hive7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome/18548518#18548518), [koningdavid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208826/preventing-relayout-due-to-scrollbar/19209057#19209057), [Christofer Eliasson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341465/prevent-a-centered-layout-from-shifting-its-position-when-scrollbar-appears/9341578#9341578), [Alec Gorge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423706/keeping-a-web-page-centered-when-browser-scroll-bar-appears-and-disappears/7423725#7423725), [Scott Bartell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968059/how-can-i-stop-the-scrollbar-from-displacing-my-page/12968136#12968136), [Shawn Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212538/how-to-stop-bootstrap-3-1-1-from-shift-content-left-when-scroll-bar-appears/23730758#23730758), [mVChr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369676/shifting-page-content-right-when-scroll-bar-becomes-visible/7369690#7369690), [fsn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716087/scrollbar-is-moving-page-content-to-the-left/31716367#31716367), [Damb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605667/scrollbar-shifts-content/5605720#5605720), [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605667/scrollbar-shifts-content/5605792#5605792), [Ruben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/7607206#7607206), [Michael Krelin - hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/1417954#1417954), [Melvin Guerrero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/39335954#39335954)*

Force the srollbar to always be on.

```
<style>
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
```

This solution is basically guaranteed to always work (there are some exceptions, but they're very rare), but it is aesthetically unpleasing. The scrollbar will always be seen, whether it's needed or not. While concensus is to use this solution in the `html` tag, some people suggest using it in the `body` tag.

*Consequences*

Microsoft (IE10+) has implented floating scroll bars which means your page may not be centered in it like it would be in other browsers. However, this seems to be a very minor issue.

When using structured interfaces like FancyBox, Flex-Box, or Twitter Bootstrap Modal this can cause a double-scrollbar to appear as those interfaces create their own scrollbars.

Programmers should avoid using `overflow: scroll` as this will cause both the vertical and horizontal scrollbars to appear.

**Solution #1a: An Alternative**

*Contributors: [koningdavid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208826/preventing-relayout-due-to-scrollbar/19209057#19209057), [Nikunj Madhogaria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/32285511#32285511)*

A clever alternative, but one having only a minor aesthetic difference, is to do this:

```
<style>
html {
    height: 101%;
}
</style>
```

This activates the scroll bar *background* but doesn't activate the scroll bar *tab* unless your vertical content actually overflows the bottom edge of the window. Nevertheless, it has the same weakness in that the scrollbar space is permanently consumed whether needed or not.

**Solution #1b: A More Modern Solution**

*Contributors: [Kyle Dumovic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome/39759119#39759119), [SimonDos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome/43912420#43912420)*

> *NOTE:* As of 2024, no major browser supports the `overlay` value. Supporting browsers represent less than 5% of browser usage. ([Source](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay)) Thanks to @JulGio for bringing this to our attention.

Browsers are beginning to pick up the use of the `overlay` value for scrollbars, mimicking the floating scrollbar of IE10+.

```
<style>
html {
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
</style>
```

This solution mimics the floating scrollbar in IE10+, but it is not yet available in all browsers and still has some implementation quirks. This solution is known not to work for infrastructure environments like Bootstrap Modal.

---

**Solution #2: The CSS3 Solution**

Use CSS3 to calculate widths. There are many ways to do this with advantages and disadvantages to each. Most disadvantages are due to (a) not knowing the actual scrollbar width, (b) dealing with screen resizing, and (c) the fact that CSS is slowly becoming yet-another-fully-functioning-programming language — like Javascript — but has not yet completely evolved into such. Whether or not it even makes sense for it to become such is a debate for another question.

> The argument that users may disable Javascript and so a CSS-only solution is preferable is becoming irrelevant. Client-side programming has become so ubiquitous that only the most paranoid of people are still disabling Javascript. Personally, I no longer consider this a tenable argument.

It should be noted that some solutions modify `margin` and others modify `padding`. Those that modify `margin` have a common problem: if you have navigation bars, headers, borders, etc. that use a different color than the page background this solution will expose undesirable borders. It is likely that any solution using `margin` can be re-designed to use `padding` and vice-versa.

**Solution #2a: The HTML-based Solution**

*Contributors: [TranslucentCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome/44000322#44000322), [Mihail Malostanidis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341465/prevent-a-centered-layout-from-shifting-its-position-when-scrollbar-appears/42987298#42987298)*

```
<style>
html {
    margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
    margin-right: 0;
}
</script>
```

**Solution #2b: The BODY-based Solution**

*Contributors: [Greg St.Onge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/39478654#39478654), [Moesio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/25981719#25981719), [Jonathan SI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/42764105#42764105)*

```
<style>
body {
    padding-left: 17px;
    width: calc(100vw - 17px);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1058px) {
    body {
        padding-left: 17px;
        width: calc(100vw - 17px);
    }
}
</style>
```

`100vw` is 100% of the viewport width.

*Consequences*

Some users have suggested this solution creates undesirable screen noise when the window is resized (perhaps the calculation process is occuring multiple times during the resize process). A possible workaround is to avoid using `margin: 0 auto;` to center your content and instead use the following (the `1000px` and `500px` shown in the example represent your content maximum width and half that amount, respectively):

```
<style>
body {
    margin-left: calc(50vw - 500px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
</style>
```

This is a fixed-scrollbar-width solution, which isn't browser independent. To make it browser independent, you must include Javascript to determine the width of the scrollbars. An example that calculates the width but does not re-incorporate the value is:

*Please note that the code snippet below has been posted multiple times on Stack Exchange and other locations on the Internet verbatim with no firm attribution.*

```
function scrollbarWidth() {
    var div = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div>');
    // Append our div, do our calculation and then remove it
    $('body').append(div);
    var w1 = $('div', div).innerWidth();
    div.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    var w2 = $('div', div).innerWidth();
    $(div).remove();
    return (w1 - w2);
}
```

**Solution #2c: The DIV-based Solution**

*Contributors: [Rapti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/30293718#30293718)*

Use CSS3 calculations applied directly to a container DIV element.

```
<body>
    <div style="padding-left: calc(100vw - 100%);">
    My Content
    </div>
</body>
```

*Consequences*

Like all CSS3 solutions, this is not supported by all browsers. Even those browsers that support viewport calculations do not (as of the date of this writing) support its use arbitrarily.

**Solution #2d: Bootstrap Modal**

*Contributors: [Mihail Malostanidis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341465/prevent-a-centered-layout-from-shifting-its-position-when-scrollbar-appears/42987298#42987298), [kashesandr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page/31313306#31313306)*

Users of Twitter Bootstrap Modal have found it useful to apply the following CSS3 to their HTML element.

```
<style>
html {
    width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
}
</style>
```

Another suggestion is to create a wrapper around your content wrapper that is used to auto-detect changes in the viewport width.

```
<style>
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#wrap-wrap {
    width: 100vw;
}
#content-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
</style>
```

I have not tried either of these as I do not use Bootstrap.

---

**Solution #3: The Javascript Solution**

*Contributors: [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605667/scrollbar-shifts-content/5605759#5605759), [JBH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4526528/jbh)*

This is my favorite solution as it deals with all the issues and is reasonably backward compatible to legacy browsers. Best of all, it's scrollbar-width independent.

```
<script>
function updateWindow(){
    document.body.style.paddingLeft = (window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth);
    document.body.onclick=function(){
            document.body.style.paddingLeft = (window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth);
    }
}
window.onload=updateWindow();
window.addEventListener("resize", updateWindow());
updateWindow();
</script>
```

*Consequences*

The final command to `updateWindow();` should occur just before the `</body>` tag to avoid problems with dynamically-loaded content such as Facebook Like-Boxes. It would seem that it's redundant to the `window.onload` event, but not every browser treats `onload` the same way. Some wait for asynchronous events. Others don't.

The function is executed each and every time a user clicks within the web page. Gratefully, modern computers are fast enough that this isn't much of an issue. Still….

Finally, the function should be executed after any div is asynchronously updated (AJAX). That is not shown in this example, but would be part of the ready-state condition. For example:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'false'){
            //Error processing here
        } else {
            //Success processing here
            updateWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution #3a: Measuring Scrollbar Widths**

*Contributors: [Lwyrn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome/18548909#18548909)*

This is a less valuable solution that takes the time to measure scrollbar widths.

```
<script>
var checkScrollBars = function(){
    var b = $('body');
    var normalw = 0;
    var scrollw = 0;
    if(b.prop('scrollHeight')>b.height()){
        normalw = window.innerWidth;
        scrollw = normalw - b.width();
        $('#container').css({marginRight:'-'+scrollw+'px'});
    }
}
</script>
<style>
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>
```

*Consequences*

Like other solutions, this one permanently disables the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: This is gold! Thank you so much. +1

Comment: As of December 2021, `overflow-y: overlay` is still **not supported** by Firefox (not a big issue) and Safari (both desktop and mobile). A real shame.

Comment: Solution 1b is no longer relevant. Since mid-2023, `overflow: overlay` is not supported by major browsers anymore. [Link](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay)