# How to prevent table body scroll bar from offsetting header columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Probably best explained with pictures:

Before the scroll bar appears (everything is fine):

[image]

After the scrollbar appears (headers offset)

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r2pmtL4g/

```
code
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is simply set the width of the tbody to > 100% so that the tbody has extra width for creating the scrollbar. like this:

```
.outerTable tbody {
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width:102%;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/r2pmtL4g/4/)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Now it causes the opposite problem where the headers are initially offset (before the scroll bar appears). Also when the scroll bar appears it's off-screen.

Comment: I found this post, hopefully it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524214/how-do-i-stop-my-web-content-from-shifting-left-when-the-vertical-scrollbar-appe

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I only need to support Chrome so it's fine:

```
overflow-y: overlay;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r2pmtL4g/8/